# Intellij support for UML Activity diagrams

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, activity-diagram

I can see Intellij has support for UML Class diagrams but not for UML Activity diagrams by default.Is there any Idea plugin for this and which one is practical.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only supported in Ultimate edition. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html

Comment: The question does not concern the classes but the activities

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using two:

1. [PlantUML](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration)
2. [Mermaid](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/23043-mermaid-chart)

For your case I would use Mermaid ;)